# Redirecting 404 [Not Found] Error To Homepage And Before Redirecting To Home Page, Tell Search Engines 404 Page is Gone[410] Using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-410

I googled and searched on stack over flow but i not found my answer.
in Google webmaster Tools, My site have 58,842 Not Found[404] URL Errors. I want all 404 pages redirect to home page with 410 status code using the .htaccess file. I mean before redirecting to home page, I want visitors or Search Engines redirected to home page and get 410 status code. I want tell to Search Engines that, the 404 page was permanently deleted[410] and redirect to home page. For example...

step-1 Visitors or Search Engines visits this url. this is 404 page.
 https://example.com/some-url-of-my-blog

step-2 Search Engines get HTTP/1.1  410 Gone [status code 410]
step-3 Visitors or Search Engines redirected to home page. That's it.

Is it possible in .htaccess file. Please anyone solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are really just wanting the 410 redirect on any pages and directories that do not exist.

For most cases something like this should work fine

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [L,R=410]
```

Comment: But I also want 410 redirect to home page.  1st tells to search engine that the 404 page is gone [HTTP Status code is 410] and then 410 redirect to homepage.

Comment: I want more to clearly explain it. 1-Server send 410 status code **[to the browser or crawler]** for 404 error page and then 410 error page redirect the browser or search crawler to the home page.